# IS sensors command from lm-sensos able to find all the internal and external sensor devices?

Tags: sensors, lm-sensors

I am not sure about the detected list of sensor explored with `sensors` command provided by `lm-sensors` package.

As the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lm_sensors) of this package said:

> lm_sensors (Linux monitoring sensors) is a free and open-source application that provides tools and drivers for monitoring **temperatures**, **voltage**, and **fans**.

I am a bit doubt about:

- Does it confined / limited to all the internal sensors belongs to a computer or it can also detect external sensors (like proximity sensor, temperature, humidity and so on) connected to a computer?

I have read the manual from `man sensors` and `sensors --help` but didn't find the clear explanation.

Comment: It is unclear what "external sensor devices" you have in mind.

Comment: @mikewhatever The sensor devices whose are connected through I/O pins (GPIO in Raspberry Pi). For example, proximity (PIR motion), temperature, humidity sensor and so on.

Comment: In general, a system can verify a device with premature library installed into the system or the manufacturer company of a device may provide driver so that we can interact the device. For example, a computer can verify a display when it is connected through the display port (VGA/DVI/HDMI). This will a bit more complex when a mouse / keyboard connected to a computer through USB port. There maybe some on-connect program burn into the keyboard / mouse which will call when the device just connect to a computer send all the manufacturer detail.

Comment: However, this will even more complex when the devices connected trough I/O pins (as mentioned earlier). In such cases, is it possible to grab the information of the sensor or whatever it is?

Comment: You seem to make a distinction between "internal" and "external" sensors. The former are presumably connected by hardware vendors, and the latter are connected by the user. I am not sure they are different, as all of them are connected to the board one way or another. It is unlikely that all sensors that ever existed can be supported by lm-sensors without any help by hardware vendors. You hardware is Raspberry Pi specific, so this kind of question would have been better placed on a RP forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lmsensors is not magical - it can only detect built-in sensors that it learns about from interrogating the hardware.

"external" add-on sensors on GPIO won't be known to the hardware -- so additional code will be needed to read and interpret that input. Sorry.